# How can I change the font size of annotations in iTextPdf?

Tags: java, pdf, annotations, itext

I'm programming a system that generates a PDF file containing user-submitted comments. I want to reduce the size of the comments, i.e. the font size of each annotation. I'm using the Java version of iTextPdf.

My code:

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createText(pdfStamper.getWriter(),
    new Rectangle(x, valor, x+100f, valor+100f), "authors", 
    comentario.getComentario(), true, "Comment");
annotation.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
```

Can I reduce the font size like this?

```
annotation.setFontSize("2px");
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the API, I would say: no, it's not possible.

Maybe you can use the `setAppearance` method. On the iText website is an [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=142) which creates an `PdfAppearance` object that owns a `setFontAndSize` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used iTextPdf, but its API says that [the `PdfAnnotation` class](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAnnotation.html) has no `setFontSize()` method.

However, it does contain a [`setDefaultAppearanceString()` method](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAnnotation.html#setDefaultAppearanceString%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte%29), which takes [a `PdfContentByte`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfContentByte.html) as an argument. And `PdfContentByte` has [a `setFontAndSize()` method](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfContentByte.html#setFontAndSize%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont,%20float%29).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. You can set the default font & size, as Lord Torgamus described.
2. You can use the Rich Text value of the annotation, which you have to directly access using the methods PdfAnnotation inherited from PdfDictionary:

```
annotation.put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString( "<font size=\"whatever\">" + 
                                          comentario.getComentario() + 
                                          "</font>" ) );
```

Note that iText cannot render Rich Text field appearances (at least not yet), so you have to turn off appearance generation so the resulting PDF will ask the viewer to do it:

```
myStamper.setGenerateAppearances( false );
```

Yep, have to use a stamper.

It's probably just easier to go with Torg's suggestion... but mind the rabbit.  It doesn't play well with others.

PS: Splash's `setAppearance()` trick would work, but then you'd have to draw the whole thing yourself... background, borders, and text layout (which is much easier thanks to `ColumnText`).