# PDF Annotations using JAVA

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I've been trying to add annotations to an existing PDF using the iText API and the older Lowagie version. However, I need alternatives to the API since it does not seem to be able to do what is asked in our requirement.

The requirement is to put an Annotation into an existing PDF with the following details:

- Type:            plain text
- Postion:         x=0mm && y=0mm
- Font:            Arial
- Text Colour:     White
- Text Content:    "some text"

Using iText, I can put in an annotation but I need to approximate in pixels where in my A4 size page I should put it. The closest approximation is using

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(headerFilePath.concat(xmlFileName));
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(headerFilePath.concat(xmlFileNameNew)));
    PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createText(stamper.getWriter(), new Rectangle(0, 842, 5, 842), "some text", "some text", true, null);
    annotation.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    stamper.addAnnotation(annotation, 1);
    reader.close();
    stamper.close();
```

This snippet places it at the top left corner but I'm not sure if it's 0mm,0mm. Also it is black and I cannot specify the font.

Any help on the matter is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try rich text annotions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340541/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-annotations-in-itextpdf):

```
annotation.put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString( "<font size=\"whatever\">" + 
                                      some text+ 
                                      "</font>" ) );
myStamper.setGenerateAppearances( false );
```

However I doubt that this is what you need. If you add an appearance then you'll get an rectangular icon in the upper left corner. If you then hover with you mouse over it you are able to read the annotation in form of a pop up. And even if you get a white font color of the annotation text you can't hide the rectangular icon of the annotation itself...

You want to have a white font color which indicates that you want to "transport" some hidden (white color on white background) information. Maybe in this case you may use the following mechanism ( which is normally used for adding watermarks etc.):

```
String text;
int pageNumber

PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(pageNumber);

overContent.beginText();
overContent.setFontAndSize(yourFont, yourFontSize);
//overContent.setGrayFill(...);
overContent.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, yourText + " Center", 150, 760, 0);
overContent.endText();
```

**Update**: To set an annotation to invisble add to your code:

```
annotation.setColor(Color.WHITE);
//set visibility to 0 (invisble). All values between 0...1 are possible
//so 0.5 means 50% opacity
annotation.put(PdfName.CA, new PdfNumber(0));
```

Comment: Yeah. The company insists on using Arial as the font since it's what the system recognizes. Would you know how to put invisible Annotations? I've tried PDFBox with setHidden and setInvisible as true but it does not work. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to tag you on my question. Sorry.

Comment: thanks! Lastly, is there a way to not use a Rectangle for the annotation? Or is this necessary for PDFBox and iText?

Comment: Do you mean the rectangle where the text "some text" is shown? This has nothing to do with iText or PDFBox - this is the way annotations are represented on the screen and its the way adobe reader shows it - maybe other readers do it differently. If you want to directly print the text into the PDF see my other suggestion with the overContent.

Comment: I mean is there a way that I won't use a rectangle for my text? I'll try to look into overContent.. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you are correct. I managed to find a way using createFreeText rather than createText. Thanks!